# JavaFX Scene Builder - Using Variable Values

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to use Scene Builder to handle a complicated GUI I'm working on and for the sake of simplicity I'm trying to fix the window's height and width to half of the user's screen height.

The problem I'm encountering is that Scene Builder won't let me enter custom values into the "Pref Width" and "Pref Height" fields, and will only let me enter something along the lines of "USE_COMPUTED_SIZE"

Looking directly at the FXML file, I found this:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="0.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="sudokusolver.FXMLDocumentController">
```

But I've been unable to find possible replacement values for "-Infinity" anywhere.  I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight() / 2;
```

Any tips or ideas on how to customize values like this?

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm, okey...

I'm not sure what are you looking for, if you need to set the height and width of your windows to the half of user's screen height and width, there are many way for it, the easiest one is like this:

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {

        Parent page = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("Untitled.fxml"));

        // get the user's screen size
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        // get width and height of screen and divide them by two
        double width = screenSize.getWidth()/2;
        double height = screenSize.getHeight()/2;

        // set the result to the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(page,width,height);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Window with half size of screen");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();

    }
}
```

In addition you've said "Fix the window's height and width ...", If you mean to forbid the user to resize the window so you can use below code:

```
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```

Comment: So there's no way to do it with Scene Builder or the FXML file, basically?  Because the code you provided is just a fully fleshed-out version of my example line of code that I was trying to achieve through the Scene Builder.

Comment: @steinybear: fortunately or unfortunately there is no way to have dynamic width or height for a FXML files, in FXML files, you must set its height and value.

although if you need you can change the size of Windows( Stages ) in each Controller class of FXML file. as  you know we can define a controller class for each fxml file, so you can set new height or width to your Stage.

Keep it mind, that fxml files are independent files that don't have any relation with your screen, so must do your needs just by java code ( until now, maybe in future Oracle release new features, but i don't think ...)